# How to setup Identity Server 3 for IOS client using Authorization Code flow

Tags: ios, security, oauth-2.0, identityserver3, openid-connect

Lately I've bee playing around with Thinktecture's Identity Server 3 and more specifically clients and flows. Now I want to see how the communication happens between **native IOS application** and **Identity Server 3** using **Authorization Code flow**.

What I've done so far is consuming the STS(Identity Server 3) by ASP.NET Mvc client(Hybrid flow) and AngularJS client(Implicit Flow). The STS side looks like this:

**Implicit flow client setup on STS**:

```
new Client 
            {
                ClientId = "implicitangularclient",
                ClientName = "Angular client (Implicit)",
                Flow = Flows.Implicit, 
                AllowAccessToAllScopes = true,

                IdentityTokenLifetime = 10,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 120,
                // If we want to have SSO between Angular app and MVC app we need to have this option set to
                // false for both the flows they implement(hybrid and implicit).
                RequireConsent = false,

                // redirect = URI of the Angular application
                RedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    "https://localhost:44555/callback.html",
                    // for silent refresh
                    "https://localhost:44555/silentrefreshframe.html"
                },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>()
                {
                    "https://localhost:44555/index.html"
                }
            }
```

**Hybrid flow client setup on STS**:

```
new Client 
            {
                ClientId = "hybridclient",
                ClientName = "Mvc client (Hybrid)",
                Flow = Flows.Hybrid, 
                AllowAccessToAllScopes = true,
                // If we want to have SSO between Angular app and MVC app we need to have this option set to
                // false for both the flows they implement(hybrid and implicit).
                RequireConsent = false,

                IdentityTokenLifetime = 10,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 120,

                // redirect = URI of the MVC application
                RedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    "https://localhost:44556"
                },
                
                // Needed when requesting refresh tokens
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>()
                {
                    new Secret("hybridflowsecret".Sha256())
                },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>()
                {
                    "https://localhost:44556"
                }
            }
```

Well, now my goal is to setup a client which is a native IOS application using the authorization code flow. I currently have no IOS application but I wish I could make a setup for such a client so if one day I have IOS app, I can only give it the client id, client name and client secret I have already defined and let it run. I tried to find examples on the internet but didn't have success with that so I started digging into it. What I am now wondering is what the return url should be and how does it get processed client-side. Following this specification: [oauth2-native-apps-03](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps-03#ref-iOS.URIScheme), starting from [section 5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps-03#section-5). It says that

> There are three main approaches to redirection URIs for native apps:
> custom URI schemes, app-claimed HTTPS URI schemes, and loopback
> redirects.

So far, so good, but as far as I understand, on the client side app we need to **register custom URI scheme** which I've never done before(I've never done ios development in general). Even more, we need to open the app after a specific URL(most likely, the ReturnUris url) is passed to the phone browser that launched the authorization process. I also spent some time on [Inter App communication for IOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html) but didn't really get the answer of my question which is: **If I want to abstract myself from the IOS application and its setup and I want to configure only the STS, how could I do that in terms of setting up the Client object for this case on STS level? What should be the redirect uri(As far as I understand it is kind of reverse DNS notation. Something like com.mycompany.apples)? Just imagine I am STS administrator and a physical client comes to me and says: *Hey, I have IOS application with this id, this secret and that return uri, please set it up for me on your STS.***

Comment: Any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Xamarin project [iOS Client example](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/master/iOSClient/iOSClient) using the following libraries.

- [IdentityModel.OidcClient](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient2) 2.0.0
- [IdentityModel](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2) 2.5.1

If you are going to use Xamarin then the ViewController.cs has the login code to connect to an IdentityServer.

```
        var options = new OidcClientOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io",
            ClientId = "native.hybrid",
            Scope = "openid profile email api",
            RedirectUri = "io.identitymodel.native://callback",

            ResponseMode = OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.Redirect
        };

        _client = new OidcClient (options);
        _state = await _client.PrepareLoginAsync ();

        AppDelegate.CallbackHandler = HandleCallback;
        safari = new SafariServices.SFSafariViewController (new NSUrl (_state.StartUrl));

        this.PresentViewController (safari, true, null);
```

If you are going to be using a Single Page Application SPA then they have a good [sample project](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/tree/dev/sample/public) their that uses their oidc-client.js library with the documentation [here](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki).

**NOTE: I have not had any luck using a URL Scheme with the oidc-client.js library. I'm still looking into if this library supports that ability.**

If you were planning on using Cordova for your project then here is a source that I've tested with. NOTE: There are some testing issues you may run into if you don't have a iOS device to test with. I ran into this issue and was able to test using the [Intel XDX tool](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk), which allows you to push the Cordova project to a test server and launch on your mobile device via the [Intel App Preview](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/intel-xdk-app-preview-overview) application.

- [jquery-cordova-oauth2](https://github.com/krisrak/jquery-cordova-oauth2): jQuery plugin for doing Oauth2 login in a Cordova App.
  The plugin relies on another [cordova inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)